# Полные права на "свои" объекты в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, users

Подскажите как дать пользователю полные права на объекты, которые создавал он? И на создание объектов конечно:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на создание объектов

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE,..  TO <user>
```

разрешения на созданные пользователем объекте устанавливаются в общем порядке в пределах его прав на базе и сервере